# Linq query in LinqPad is read-only?

Tags: linqpad

Are all Linq queries(query data from MSSQL) in LinqPad are read only? I can't edit data, only read it. Right?

Query below produce read only view and I do not find a way to edit data.

```
from u in Users
where u.Email == "my@mail.com" 
select u
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can execute any query in LINQPad, including inserts, updates and deletes.

More info about editing data with LINQ to SQL here:

- [Insert, Update, and Delete Operations (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386931.aspx)

Comment: If I execute query above(refer to my original post) can I expect editable data?

Comment: Ah, I see. I need to script all changes in Linq and execute SubmitChanges.

Answer (score 0):

not right, when object linking is not disabled in the initializer objects can be accessed, updated. They will NOT be updated in the database, you will still have to do an SubmitChanges.

Comment: I have created MSSQL connection and executed the query(please refer to my original post). I get read only result as HTML web page. How to get editable queries?

Comment: Object linking is by default on, the result of your query gives an object, you can edit this object and use SubmitChanges() to update the database.